# Get group of checkboxes by name attribute in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I am trying to get a group of checkboxes by the name attribute.  For example, I have the following:

```
<input name="labs[]" type="checkbox" value="lab1" />
<input name="labs[]" type="checkbox" value="lab2" />
<input name="labs[]" type="checkbox" value="lab3" />
<input name="labs[]" type="checkbox" value="lab4" />
```

And Im trying to get that group by doing something like:

```
Ext.query('input[name=labs[]]');
```

But that clearly doesn't work because of the square brackets that are part of the name.  I'm lost as to how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a "starts with" match instead:

```
Ext.query('input[name^=labs]');
```

This will not work very well if you have other elements that start with "labs" though, so you may want to add another identifier to your "labs[]" name, i.e. "labs-check[]".

Comment: In this particular case, I do not have anything else starting with 'labs', but thank you for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

Try matching an input element that has a name attribute that starts with 'labs':

```
Ext.query("input[name^=labs]");
```